# What is the best type of Arduino board for simple delivery robot?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-mega, arduino-nano, arduino-due, arduino-yun

I'm new to arduino, and I want to design a Simple Delivery Robot for Data Center, which has an arm to move items, and it follows line while moving.

I have no idea if there is a special arduino board for these types of robot or I can buy any arduino board.

Comment: This is presently unanswerable, as you cannot pick hardware (or at least not limited hardware like an Arduino) until you have determined *how* the robot will function.  In your case that seems to be mostly an issue of navigation and safety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANWSER**

I would suggest you to use the Arduino UNO for all the shields that it has. Most Arduinos are so similar that it wont make a difference but the UNO has many shields to it, including a motor/servo shield which is going to be great for your project.

But at the end of the day, it's your project and you can pretty much use any of the boards listed below. They are just advantages and disadvantages of many popular board. Hope it helped you!

**The summary has been removed for the sake of respecting Stack Exchanges rules.**

Comment: This is a re-used answer, and copy-and-pasting answers (even your own) is inappropriate on stack exchange sites (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions ) this is especially true in this case where the posting does not even really address any aspects of the question.  If this were the answer, the question would need to be closed as too broad, opinionated, or a duplicate of an existing question on which arduino to start with.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, is it better now?

Answer (score 1):

Arduino UNO is the best arduino board for simple projects.
but if you want to add modules like LCD screen and some wireless sensors like bluetooth and RF and you want to make it with more motors then you should probably use Arduino Mega. It is better to use simple DC geared motors.